# Failed when build qtwayland in Yocto

Tags: qt, yocto, qtwayland

I am building qt framework with Yocto Rocko, I ran into below error when building qtwayland package.

```
| ERROR: Error calling /LTSI4.9/R-Car_SKM3ULCB/LTSI4.4/porter/tmp/work/armv7vehf-neon-vfpv4-agl-linux-gnueabi/qtwayland/5.8.0+gitAUTOINC+0e2a950895-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qt5/qmake -makefile -o Makefile       /LTSI4.9/R-Car_SKM3ULCB/LTSI4.4/porter/tmp/work/armv7vehf-neon-vfpv4-agl-linux-gnueabi/qtwayland/5.8.0+gitAUTOINC+0e2a950895-r0/git/qtwayland.pro  --   -no-feature-drm-egl-server -no-feature-libhybris-egl-server -no-feature-wayland-brcm -feature-wayland-client -feature-wayland-egl -feature-wayland-server -no-feature-xcomposite-egl -no-feature-xcomposite-glx
| 
| Running configuration tests...
| Done running configuration tests.
| 
| Configure summary:
| 
| Qt Wayland Drivers:
|   EGL .................................... no
|   Rasberry Pi ............................ no
|   XComposite EGL ......................... no
|   XComposite GLX ......................... no
|   DRM EGL ................................ no
|   libhybris EGL .......................... no
| Qt Wayland Client ........................ yes
| Qt Wayland Compositor .................... yes
| 
| Note: No wayland-egl support detected. Cross-toolkit compatibility disabled.
| 
| ERROR: Feature 'wayland-egl' was enabled, but the pre-condition 'features.wayland-client && features.opengl && features.egl && libs.wayland-egl' failed.
| 
| ERROR: Feature 'wayland-egl' was enabled, but the pre-condition 'features.wayland-server && features.opengl && features.egl && libs.wayland-egl' failed.
| 
| Check config.log for details.
| 
| ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at .../temp/log.do_configure.16034)
```

The building progress was failed at do_configure task. I believed that due to certain missed things from wayland-egl. Any idea can help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to add wayland feature to the DISTRO feature in local.conf

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_NATIVESDK_append = " wayland"
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " wayland"
```

The Yocto build is successful now. Cheers!

Comment: This fix is not working for me. I see that in the logs,
Qt Wayland Drivers:
|   EGL .................................... no , <- this should be yes.

Comment: It seemed that your platform didn't have libegl.

Comment: If you want it, add more line in your local.conf: PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/egl = "libegl" (provided by mesa).

Answer (score 1):

15.0 version qtwayland i got same issue.

i created qtwayland_%.bbappend file included

```
PACKAGECONFIG_remove_pn-qtwayland = "xcomposite-glx"
```

or else add above line your local.conf

In my case problem is solved.

Comment: This fix is working for me  for a build on rpi4-64.